# C#/ASP.NET Web Site using SQL Server CE Database Slow Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce, iis-8

The main issue I have is that a simple select from my SQL Server CE database has a typical wait time of 17 seconds for the first query and ~5 seconds for each subsequent query.

After letting the site sit idle for a couple minutes, the 17 second delay comes back. I am assuming the delay is from establishing connections, caching, etc, but I feel on our LAN this is a ridiculous wait and will only get worse for outside users.

The site is a c#/ASP.NET web site that is using a SQL Server Compact database (v4.0.8876.1). This is deployed to an IIS8 server. The site is intended to calculate values from user input using coefficients for different models that are stored in the database.

What am I doing wrong for there to be such a massive delay during the connection/queries?

Connection string:

```
<add name="DatabaseConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

Query:

```
string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connstr))
{
    string queryString = @"Select id, description, imagePath
                           from ConservationModels
                           where model = @modelName";

    SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(queryString, conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modelName", modelName);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            modelID = (int)reader[0];
            description = (string)reader[1];
            imagePath = (string)reader[2];
        }

        reader.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        throw;
     }
 }
```

Apologies for any missing information and I appreciate any suggestions. If there is a better way to achieve the goal for a web site, I am all ears.

Comment: Do not assume, measure. How many records in the table? Is the Model field indexed?

Comment: 74 records and no it's not indexed. I realize now that needs to happen as the ID is the primary key. I'll update shortly once I figure that out. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: 74 records should not have any kind of effect on your waiting time. Perhaps the first wait could be caused by ASP.NET recompiling your code but then it should work without any delay

Comment: Got the index in and it reduced first query to 15.4 seconds. Still too much. This is also not on the initial load of the site. That on its own takes a bit but I figured that was the compiling I had read about.

Comment: We need an Sql Server CE expert to look at this question. I can't find in your code any weakness that could cause such a delay

Comment: Why the hell are you using SQL Server CE on a web server?! Go with SQL Server Express

Comment: I was thrown into web development for this and a couple other requests. I'm just wading and learning my way through (apologies for my idiocy). Why is SQL CE such a bad idea for a web site? It seemed to make sense to have a stand-alone database and not the overhead of a separate database server on the web server.

Comment: I have some tips here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/01/entity-framework-with-sql-server.html (the Deployment section)

Comment: A couple things regarding that. This will greatly reduce the initial loading of the site rather than the query and if it's a 15 second delay people will think it's broken, I fear. Also, everything I've read says connections should be closed once used (to use the 'using' logic), is this incorrect? That said, I'll attempt this today and we'll see how it goes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following MatteoSp's advice, I removed SQL Server CE components from the site and created a SQL Server Express database to replace it.  Though the compilation time on the site seems to have increased for some reason, this resolved my issue for the slow queries/connection.

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This may be belated, but I recent found out (the hard way), that if you use SQL Server CE with ASP.NET on OWIN hosted on IIS, IIS will recompile or build a new app domain on *every* request.  No idea why this happens, but the time you're seeing is likely to be ASP.NET rebuilding the application.

My application originally uses SQL Server Express with Entity Framework and everything works fine -- typical slow response on the first request as Entity Framework compiles the database schema, then lightning-fast afterwards.  Static variables on the application carry across multiple requests.

I moved from SQL Server Express to SQL Server CE, and then suddenly I see Entity Framework recompiling the schema on *every* request.  That means that **every** request is now slow.

Also, any static variables I keep on the application is reset for every request -- consistent with a new app domain being built.

Moving the whole stack unchanged to self-hosting on OWIN and suddenly it becomes normal again -- the first request slow, the subsequent ones lightning-fast.

This proves that ASP.NET on OWIN on IIS with SQL Server CE is doing something weird by not reusing existing threads and constantly building new app domains.